hard disk not showed
sorry for the English and if the question is not strictly related to the forum but I need help.
when I plug my hard disk it seems to start and run, but after a few seconds it stops and an error appears:  [sdb] Asking for cache data failed and [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through.
the disk is no longer visible with lsblk so i can't check it with smartctl, and the disk LED always stays on.
when the disk spins it is visible on lsusb, but when it stops it disappears from there too.
I checked the logs and this is what appears:
Jul 30 00:29:43 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev multipath[2353]: sysfs_is_multipathed: error scanning /sys/block/sdb/holders
Jul 30 00:29:46 srvkev systemd-udevd[2351]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 30 00:29:47 srvkev multipathd[462]: sdb: path already removed

I would add that the disk was not dropped and was not damaged in any way, it was always connected to the PC as the backups of my main computer and some additional files were saved, the other day while I was using it it stopped loading and it stopped disconnected. also add that as soon as it is connected it turns it makes a small noise but it doesn't seem like a "bad" sound to me, it sounds like a normal hard disk when the head moves.
thanks

All storage media eventually die. Your output indicates that yours has died.
It may have lasted longer than average because of your good care (not dropping it), but has finally succumbed.
If your storage media was still within warranty, notify the manufacturer for a replacement.

So you're saying there's no way to recover what was inside? not so much for backups but for individual files

Ubuntu has free data recovery applications that you are welcome to try. They work in some circumstances. If your circumstance is not among them, then there are paid data recovery services. Use the Search box at the top of the page ("data recovery") to learn more about the free applications.
